# In cypress , when i am writing code to handle a web table - how to select a particular table?

Tags: xmlhttprequest, cypress

[image: web table]

It is not executing my entire code, it stops after the first two lines of code and throws something like this in the image. please help me out.

Comment: Please add the error which you have got.

Comment: Please add the Cypress code you've tried